# Variable Cells in UITable

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to build TableView like this.

[Click Here to See Table View Mock up Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJm5i.png)

It is not problem for fixed cells.

But problem is cells are variable.

As you can see the picture, if you press "Mould" in 2nd section then 3rd section shows Mould cells only.

These properties are all in every section.

How to build table view like this?

Comment: by variable you mean they sometimes are available and sonetimes not?(visibility)

Comment: yeah, i mean that.

Comment: change the cell height for all the cellls you want invisible to 0, then reload table [yourTable reloadData];